# How to develop an online ERC20 wallet

Tags: web3js, wallets, frontend

I'm looking for any tutorials on how to create my own token wallet.

Example:

Create token for website purchases
I implement my own wallet for token and allow ppl to buy with token and redeem prizes with it.

Just out of curiosity I'm trying to see the difficulty in this. I'm not to good with code but will be determined to do it. And I have time to learn.

So if anyone has info about this. Or can point me into the right direction it would be helpful. Maybe some links

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this article below

https://medium.com/coinmonks/a-simple-erc20-exchange-wallet-c6720e6c8005

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any tutorials anywhere on how to create your own online wallet, unless you're looking for wallet creation through MEW, MIST or similar (Which I don't think you're referring to) However, here is a link to an opensourced online ERC20 wallet created by the secret-tech team. It's pretty nice and there's both a frontend and backend repository for you to study. https://github.com/secret-tech/frontend-moon-wallet

Comment: Thinks for the reply sorry it took so long to log back on can't remember where I posted this.  I'm fine with using the etherum wallet for a token. But would I be able to set my own transaction fees apart from the network fees. And would I be able to set up a way for ppl to get tokens back once they feel out a form. I'm gonna look at the link. And see what it is. But I'm fine with just using a standard wallet that allows me to edit transaction fees and allows me to give back token after a form is filled out